# Prove $\int_{0}^{1}x^{m}P_{l}(x)dx = \frac{m! (m - l + 1)!!}{(m - l +1)!(m + l +1)!!}$

Tags: integration, legendre-polynomials

I used the Rodrigues formula and integrated by parts:
$$ \dfrac{1}{2^{l}l!}\int_{0}^{1}x^{m}\dfrac{d^{l}}{dx^{l}}(x^2 - 1)^{l}dx = \dfrac{1}{2^{l}l!}[ x^{m}\dfrac{d^{l-1}}{dx^{l-1}} (x^{2} - 1)^{l} - \int_{0}^{1} m x^{m-1}\dfrac{d^{l-1}}{dx^{l-1}} (x^{2} - 1)^{l}dx] $$
The first term vanishes due to the integration extremes. Then integrating by parts m times:
$$\dfrac{1}{2^{l}l!}[(-1)^{m}m!\int_{0}^{1}\dfrac{d^{l-m}}{dx^{l-m}}(x^{2} - 1)^{l}dx]$$

But I don't know how to develop from here!

Comment: Continue integrate by parts you'll meet an integral which we call a Beta function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint:

It is clear from the RHS of your equation that the inequality $m\ge l-1$ is assumed. To incorporate the case $m=l-1$ we will follow the same path as you proposed but stop after $l-1$ integrations by parts to obtain:

$$\dfrac{1}{2^{l}l!}\left[\frac{m!(-1)^{l-1}}{(m-l+1)!}\int_{0}^{1}x^{m-l+1}\frac d{dx}(x^{2}-1)^{l}dx\right]=\dfrac{1}{2^{l}l!}\left[\frac{m!\,2l}{(m-l+1)!}\int_{0}^{1}x^{m-l+2}(1-x^{2})^{l-1}dx\right].$$

It remains to prove:
$$
\int_{0}^{1}x^{m-l+2}(1-x^{2})^{l-1}dx=\frac{(m-l+1)!!\,(2l-2)!!}{(m+l+1)!!}.
$$

Can you take it from here?

Comment: Yes!! I was able to finish from here, thank you so much!

Comment: You're welcome.